# Get the version of an installed Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

How can I get the installed version of my Firefox extension, e.g. to show it in the About dialog?

Comment: By "plugin" you probably mean an extension? What do you mean by "get current version"? Find out which version is installed or find out which version is the newest available on the update server/install it?

Comment: Yes, by plugin I mean extension. I'd like to know what it's version and, for instance, show it on my 'About' dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the [AddonManager API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager):

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
AddonManager.getAddonByID("id@my.addon", function(addon)
{
  alert("Installed version is " + addon.version);
});
```

Here `id@my.addon` needs to be replaced by the ID of your add-on of course.